# Windows Phone 8 no Button Image?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8, xamarin

Im working on a Xamarin cross-platform project. I'm placing an image on a button with XAML code and it works fine on Android. But on Windows Phone 8 there is no Image. I tried it with the Code-behind workaround but it is still the same. So my question is, is it even possible to have a button with an image on it on Windows Phone 8 (without any custom renderer)? The image is placed in the Assets directory where it sould be. I'm not a Windows Phone user so I have no idea, if it's even possible.

```
I try to break it down:

<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
       <Button Margin="5,0,5,5"
                        AutomationId="InspectionButton"
                        BackgroundColor="Red"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                        ContentLayout="Right, 100"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        HeightRequest="90"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Image="whiteArrorw.png"
                        Text="Test"
                        TextColor="White" />
    </StackLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks

Comment: Code? Where is the button placed?

Comment: The XAML version is now in my first post

Comment: I can't find the link about it, but I think you can't add images to a folder in your project in UWP. I know it's ugly, but try to add the image under your project and then see if it works. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/awPzHrk.png

Comment: wow this works, but it's realy ugly. Isn't there another possibility?
Other images which are not placed in a button are working from the Assets folder.

Comment: I really can't find the link but I know that you could place it in a folder, but then you have to do ugly stuff in iOS/Android to make it work there :( I remember that I prefered the ugly workaround in UWP rather than changing stuff for iOS/Android... Sorry that I can't help more

Comment: But it is working, thats the main part. thank you :)